# Rearranging rows in a file based on a source file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file A, that describes the order of rows that looks like this:

```
ddr_mode,8,#tc_reg
gasket_ratio,7,#tc_reg
txX_ropll_refsel_override,0,#tc_reg,4
mpllb_word_clk_en,0,#tc_reg
mplla_word_clk_en,1,#tc_reg
```

I have another file B, from which I need to extract the rows in the order defined by File A. File B looks like this:

```
tc gen3_ddr_mode       8
tc gen3_ddr_mode       8
tc gen3_gasket_ratio       7
tc gen3_gasket_ratio       7
tc gen3_mplla_word_clk_en       1
tc gen3_mplla_word_clk_en       1
tc gen3_mpllb_word_clk_en       0
tc gen3_mpllb_word_clk_en       0
tc tx0_ropll_refsel_override  0
tc tx1_ropll_refsel_override  0
tc tx2_ropll_refsel_override  0
tc tx3_ropll_refsel_override  0
tc tx0_ropll_refsel_override  0
tc tx1_ropll_refsel_override  0
tc tx2_ropll_refsel_override  0
tc tx3_ropll_refsel_override  0
```

The output file should look like this:

```
tc gen3_ddr_mode       8
tc gen3_gasket_ratio       7
tc tx0_ropll_refsel_override  0
tc tx1_ropll_refsel_override  0
tc tx2_ropll_refsel_override  0
tc tx3_ropll_refsel_override  0
tc gen3_mpllb_word_clk_en       0
tc gen3_mplla_word_clk_en       1
tc gen3_ddr_mode       8
tc gen3_gasket_ratio       7
tc tx0_ropll_refsel_override  0
tc tx1_ropll_refsel_override  0
tc tx2_ropll_refsel_override  0
tc tx3_ropll_refsel_override  0
tc gen3_mpllb_word_clk_en       0
tc gen3_mplla_word_clk_en       1
```

Notice how the order is defined by File A and data is extracted from File B. Also, note that `txX_ropll_refsel_override,0,#tc_reg,4` is extracted 4-times. **4** at the end indicates the number of times it should be extracted. Is there a better way to do this in Python?

EDIT=====
I tried the following to code to match any keyword in File A with File B.

```
with open('file_a.txt', 'r') as k:
    keywords = k.read().splitlines()

results = []

with open('file_b.txt') as f, open('output.txt', 'w') as o:
    for line in f:
        if any(key in line for key in keywords):
            o.writelines(line)
```

But I am not getting any output. Ofcourse even if this works, this won't fix the repeated extraction.

Comment: show some code that you have written

Answer (score 0):

The following *almost* works, except that your keys don't seem to follow a stable pattern. If you can fix that, the rest works:

```
def do_sort(key_filename, data_filename, out_filename):
    with open(key_filename) as key_file:
        order = {line.partition(',')[0]: i for i, line in enumerate(key_file)}
    with open(data_filename) as data_file:
        data = sorted(data_file, key=lambda line: order[line.split()[1]])
    with open(out_filename, 'w') as out_file:
        for line in data:
            print(line.rstrip('\n'), file=out_file)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    do_sort('A.txt', 'B.txt', 'B-sorted.txt')
```